# JTextArea vertical scrollbar showing up when not needed

Tags: java, user-interface

I need a vertical scrollbar in my JTextArea to only appear when it's needed, and for that I know I need to use Vertical Scrollbar As Needed. But the scrollbar keeps showing up, like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTnWf.png)

even when it's clearly not needed. What am I doing wrong?

```
// make top panel where output from the menu selections will appear
        topP = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        topP.setSize(new Dimension(500,150));
        // make default text message to be displayed in top panel
        output = new JTextArea("Output printed here...", 20, 20);
        // styles the text in the textarea
        output.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        output.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        topP.add(output, BorderLayout.NORTH); // add default text to the top panel
        right.add(output);

        // here's the scrollbar guys
        top = new JScrollPane(output); // applies to the textarea
        top.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,150));
        top.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        top.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        topP.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: I think your scrollbar is appearing due to problems with your layout. Did you notice you're adding your textarea `output` to two different containers? Where is the container `right`defined?

Comment: `right` is a JPanel defined as `right = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 10,10));
        right.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,500));`. And I tried commenting out each of the output.add lines - only adding it to the topP, then only adding it to the container `right`, but there was no difference in the scrollbar behavior.

Comment: Did you see the answer?

Comment: I did and it worked for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) for JTextArea. If you scroll down to the constructor summary section, you'll see the following:

> JTextArea​(String text, int rows, int columns) 
>   Constructs a new TextArea with the specified text and number of rows and columns.

This is the same as the constructor you're using:

```
output = new JTextArea("Output printed here...", 20, 20);
```

By specifying rows and columns, you're effectively telling the JTextArea that it has to be a certain size, and the scrollpane is just responding to your specifications by showing scroll controls. Those scroll controls are displayed based on the number of rows and columns you asked for, as opposed to the amount of visible text within the text area.

If you construct a JTextArea without specifying rows and columns, there won't be any scrollbars. Since you're setting the size of the text area, specifying rows and columns is redundant anyhow. Just don't do it.

Note: You should avoid setting the absolute size of Swing components. Set a preferred size only, and when you call `pack()`, Swing will try to accommodate your specification as much as possible. When you specify absolute sizes, your UI can look really bad on different platforms or when a user resizes the frame.